# Where to host my NodeJS powered socket.io API?

Tags: node.js, database, socket.io, cloud, hosting

I'm currently working on an api for an app that I'm developing, which I don't want to tell too much about. I'm a solo dev with no patents so it's probably a good idea to keep it anonymous. It uses socket.io together with node.js to interact with clients and the other way around, which I might be swapping out sometime later for elixir and it's sockets, but that isn't relevant for now. Now I'm trying to look into cloud hosting, but I'm having a rough time finding a good service to use.

These are my requirements:

- 24/7 uptime
- Low memory and performance necessary (at least to start with). About 1+ gig with 2+ cores will most likely suffice (need 2 threads or more for node to handle async programming well)
- Preferably free for like maybe even a year, or just really cheap, but that might be munch to ask
- Must somehow be able to run some sort of database. Haven't really settled on this yet, but I want to implement a custom currency at some point, and probably have the ability to add some cooldowns. So it can be fairly simple and small. If anybody has any tips on what database I should use, that would also be very welcome. I was thinking of Cassandra because of the blazing fast performance and expandability. But I also wanna look into remote databases, especially if I'm gonna go international with the product
- Ability to keep open socket.io connections, as you've probably guessed :P
- Low ping decently high bandwith internet. The socket.io connections are lightweight and not a lot of data has to be sent. Mostly packets of a few kilobytes every now and then for all of the clients.

If this information is too vague or you want to know some other requirements I haven't thought of, let me know.

Comment: I don't think this type of question is really on-topic for stackoverflow as its about hosting infrastructure, not questions about software.  I'm not sure where you would ask this.  Perhaps in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Heroku (PaaS), they have a free version to start with